# I want to make listview Item under item (android)

Tags: android, listview

I want to make them (item under item) mine is (2 items under 2 items) how i can change them i want to show the items normal ?

[image]

**card.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:id="@+id/txt_reference1"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/txt_des1"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_des1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/txt_prix1"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_idArticle1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                android:id="@+id/txt_idArticle" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_reference1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_idArticle"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_idArticle"
                android:id="@+id/txt_reference" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_reference"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_reference"
                android:id="@+id/txt_des" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txt_prix"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_prix1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_prix1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_des"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_des" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**recherche_article.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_recherche_article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bacha.pfe.RechercheArticle">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The way your RecyclerView shows the list items inside it depends on its `LayoutManager`. Since it's not set in the XML, it will be in the Java code somewhere, looks like right now it's a `GridLayoutManager`, you'll need a `LinearLayoutManager` instead.

Answer (score 0):

thnx , all is ok now :

**old code** :

```
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
```

**new code** :

```
gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
```

i just change the GridLayoutManager size that's all